# git diff: specify different highlighter as commandline option

Tags: git, command-line, diff

I have this in my `.gitconfig`:

```
[pager]
    show = diff-highlight
    diff = diff-highlight
```

When I do `git diff`, then`diff-highlight` is used for color highlighting.

How can I specify on the command line a different highlighter? I want to use `diffr`, without changing the default in `.gitconfig`.

I tried `git difftool --tool=diffr` but this does nit work, and it seems this is different from what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set environment variable `PAGER` or [`GIT_PAGER`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt-codeGITPAGERcode) for the command:

```
GIT_PAGER=diffr git diff
```

Or [set](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt--cltnamegtltvaluegt) the config value at the command line once:

```
git -c pager.diff=diffr diff
```

*Upd*. The following command creates an alias:

```
git config --global alias.diffr '!GIT_PAGER=diffr git diff'
```

The alias can be used with parameters:

```
git diffr HEAD~
```

Comment: thank you. Can I use the environment variable `GIT_PAGER` inside an alias? For instance, I would like to create an alias `git diffr`, that would do what `GIT_PAGER=diffr git diff` does

Comment: @400theCat See the update about an alias.